# Evaluating a multivariable function with constraints

Tags: r

I have a function f(x,y) where both the inputs are integers. Given a natural number K, I would like to evaluate f at all points in the set `{ (x,y) : 0 <= x <= K-1 , x < y <= K }`. In other words, evaluating f at all feasible `0 <=x,y <= K` which satisfy `y>x`.

I know this can be done with nested for loops but I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to do it through one of the apply functions perhaps.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of doing what the question asks for. It's a simple double `*apply` loop with a function call in the inner most loop.

```
f <- function(x, y) {x + y + x*y}

K <- 10
sapply(0:(K - 1), function(x){
  sapply((x + 1):K, function(y) f(x, y))
})
```

This is easily rewritten as a function of `K` and `f`.

```
fun <- function(K, FUN){
  f <- match.fun(FUN)
  lapply(0:(K - 1), function(x){
    sapply((x + 1):K, function(y) f(x, y))
  })
}

fun(10, f)
```